# Okta- spring mvc integration

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, okta

I am new to Okta. We already have application in spring mvc with oauth jwt token. Need to enable Okta on it. Please provide a basic sample Oauth2 Okta with spring MVC application. Many applications are with spring boot, I am able to do poc with spring boot but stuck with MVC.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-okta. But your question shall be better formed or is going to have negative votes, normally you can show the code you have tried for example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.